# flex textflow text highliter

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I have a flex datagrid in my application. In that I have a itemrenderer as textflow on canvas. Now I would like to implement Find/Replace functionality on the itemrenderers of the datagrid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok,

Doing one-by-one. I have a textflow & I need to highlight some text in that. While finding if the pattern matches then highlight that text.

Expecting a favorable reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to extend the itemRenderer you are using to have some way to identifying the data associated with each of them.

itemRenderer's are reused in the display, so there's not one unique renderer for each of your items.

I don't know if I'm being clear.